Linear Independence in Polynomial Quotient Ring $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n] / I$ given any Groebner basis for $I$ in SageMath
This comes from Cox, Little, and O'Shea's Using Algebraic Geometry Chapter 2, Section 1, Exercise 2.

I have shown that such $p_i(x_i)$ is a generator of $k[x_i] \cap I$.
However, I am not sure how to actually find the monic generator of this ideal.
This would be easy if I could choose the monomial ordering for the Groebner basis $G$, but the question specifies any Groebner basis $G$.
Really, my question boils down to that I do not know how to even tell if $\{1, x_i\}$ is linearly independent in $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n] / I$ given the Groebner basis $G$. Zero dimensionality just seems to guarantee that the degree $m_i$ exists and is finite. I don't know what more information it gives me.

Attempt so far:
It is given in that for a Groebner basis $G$ for $I$, then each $x_i$ has an integer $m_i$ such that $x_i^{m_i} = \mathrm{LT}(g)$ for some $g \in G$.
So given any Groebner basis, I can find this $m_i$ and so I know that $\{1, x_i, \ldots, x_i^{m_i}\}$ is linearly dependent. So this gives me an algorithm but I'm not sure how to implement this in SageMath now. Perhaps this is now worth a new question?

You could reduce $1, x_i, x_i^2, \ldots$ modulo the Groebner basis until you get one that's a linear combination of the previous ones.  (You might even be able to do some optimizations along the way, such as doing an incremental Gaussian elimination - and storing what linear combination each row is as "augment" data if you need to know at the end exactly what the generator is, as opposed to just the degree of the generator.)

@DanielSchepler I'm not sure how to do this in a computer algebra system. That's mainly where I am stuck now.

Given any Groebner basis $G = \{g_1, \ldots,g_r\}$ for $I$ with respect to any monomial ordering $>$, the set $$\operatorname{NB}(I) = \mathbb{M} \setminus \operatorname{LM}(I) = \mathbb{M} \setminus \langle \operatorname{LM}(g_1),\ldots,\operatorname{LM}(g_r)\rangle$$
is a basis for the quotient $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ as a $k$-vector space, called the normal basis for $I$ with respect to $>$.
(Here $\mathbb{M}$ denotes the set of all monomials in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $\operatorname{LM}(f)$ denotes the leading monomial of $f$ with respect to $>$.)
The multivariate polynomial division algorithm that computes the remainder $r$ of a polynomial $f \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ after division by $\{g_1, \ldots, g_r\}$ is such that the result $r$ is a $k$-linear combination of monomials in $\operatorname{NB}(I)$, and by construction the reductions $\bar{f} = \bar{r}$ modulo $I$ are equal in the quotient $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$, and we write $r = \operatorname{NF}(f, I)$ for this normal form of $f$ (depending on $I$ and $>$).
Since $I$ is a zero-dimensional ideal, the normal basis $\operatorname{NB}(I)$ is finite, and so the problem of linear independence in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ becomes a problem of finite-dimensional linear algebra.
Algorithm. Compute $\operatorname{NB}(I)$ and choose an ordering of it. Iteratively construct a matrix where the $j$th column is the normal form $\operatorname{NF}(x_i^j, I)$ of $x_i^j$, expressed as a vector with respect to the ordered $k$-basis $\operatorname{NB}(I)$. Start with one column ($j=0$), and keep going until the matrix with $m_i+1$ columns has a nonzero (right) kernel element $c$, which will be such that $p = \sum_{j=0}^{m_i} c_j x_i^j$ satisfies $\bar{p} = 0$ in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$, i.e. $p \in I \cap k[x_i]$ of minimal degree.
In SageMath you have e.g. I.normal_basis(), f.reduce(G), f.monomial_coefficient(m) and M.right_kernel() available to implement this.

Thanks! I think I arrived at the fact that my personal SageMath installation is broken (Singular is not working in particular) and so the errors I was getting which led me to ask this question seem to be coming from a broken installation. However, I had not considered looking into M.right_kernel() so thank you for that pointer.
